# Cannot assign property "Text": type mismatch between "Xamarin.Forms.Binding" and "System.String"

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i want localize my app, so i'm using an IMarkupExtension.

```
[ContentProperty ("Text")]
public class TranslateExtension : IMarkupExtension
{
    ...
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public object ProvideValue (IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (Text == null)
            return "";
        ...
        return translation;
    }
}
```

my XAML

```
  <Label Text="{extensions:Translate Text={Binding Title}}"/>
```

when i debug, an error appears

> Cannot assign property "Text": type mismatch between
>   "Xamarin.Forms.Binding" and "System.String"

how can i resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
<Label Text="{extensions:Translate Title}"/>
```

Comment: It's mean translates "Title".
I want translate value of TitleProperty.

Comment: Are you sure? I have in **AppResources.resx** file pair with `Name` = _Title_ and `Value` = _Alloha_. And extension puts _Alloha_.

Comment: I think, you are using: `var manager = new ResourceManager(ResourceId,
                typeof(TranslatorExtension).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

            var translation = temp.GetString(Text, ci);` And it returns value by `Name`.

Comment: u r right. i refer [Localizing XAML](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization).

I have in LoginViewModel, property named **Title**, which will contain greeting. Like Hello,Good morning,G9....
In LoginPage.xaml, i want get value of **Title** , if it equals Hello translate to Alloha.

Comment: You have to use **RESX file** for each localization as described in article.

Comment: I has done RESX file. I use ResX Manager extension to do it.

Comment: All of static text in Page was translated. Like login,logout... i want translate dynamic text.

Comment: So, you could translate it manually on view model and just bind `<Label Text="{Binding Title}"/>`

Comment: Your way is not bad.